# AJAX + php + html - php doesn't create the file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this issue.

I'm running an HTML with AJAX:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
<------>    var return_data = hr.responseText;
<------>    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(It's not my code anyway, but from here: https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial)

It calls a PHP on server side, which is:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
$file = 'people.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "hello", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

If I'm clicking the button on HTML it gives back the "hi" to the screen, so I assume that the HTML-AJAX-PHP connection is working properly, but the file "people.txt" doesn't show up on server side.

I guess it must be some permission issue, but I can't figure it out!
PLS help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy, but frustrating one.
I need to

```
chmod 777
```

not just the .php file, but the text file as well.
Now it's working!

Comment: note that the php file itself doesnt need to have 777 file-permission

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo "hi";
    $file = 'people.txt'; // You shoud have this file in the directory where your my_parse_file.php is
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // var_dump($current); exit; // Uncomment this, if you have a error
    // Append a new data to the file
    $current .= "hello\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current); 
?>
```

Or you can try this:

```
<?php
    function file_force_contents($filename, $data, $flags = 0){
        if(!is_dir(dirname($filename))){
            mkdir(dirname($filename).'/', 0777, TRUE);
        }
        return file_put_contents($filename, $data,$flags);
    }
    $file = 'people.txt';
    file_force_contents($file,'test1 content');  // test1.txt created
    echo 'Success'; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work either, though it may be better than my code. However just found the issue on an other forum meanwhile. I add that as an answer to my original question!
Thanks for your effort!